# Обращение к столбцам таблицы

Tags: sql-server

Объясните, пожалуйста, не совсем ясно `FROM Person.Person p JOIN Person.Address a ON p.BusinessEntityID = a.AddressID , Person.Person p` это наименование столбца или таблицы?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindEmployee @EmpLName varchar(20)  
AS  
SELECT @EmpLName = RTRIM(@EmpLName) + '%';  
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, a.City  
FROM Person.Person p JOIN Person.Address a ON p.BusinessEntityID = a.AddressID  
WHERE p.LastName LIKE @EmpLName;  
GO  
EXEC FindEmployee @EmpLName = 'Barb';
```

Comment: `Объясните, пожалуйста, не совсем ясно ... это наименование столбца или таблицы?` - там есть и названия столбцов и таблиц, про что конкретно вы спрашиваете?

Comment: FROM Person.Person p JOIN Person.Address a

Comment: В обоих случаях таблицы

Comment: Если я правильно понял Person.Person это таблица. А что тогда значит Person?